# How to list all directories that do not contain a file type?

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory, os.walk

I'm trying to return a unique list (`set`) of all directories if they do not contain certain file types. If that file type is NOT found, add that directory name to a list for further auditing.

The function below will find all valid folders and add it to a set for further comparison. I'd like to extend this to only return those directories that DO NOT contain files in the `out_list`. These directories MAY contain sub-directories with file in the `out_list`. If that's TRUE, I only want that path of the folder name of the valid dir.

```
# directory = r'w:\workorder'
#
# Example:
# w:\workorder\region1\12345678\hi.pdf
# w:\workorder\region2\23456789\test\bye.pdf
# w:\workorder\region3\34567891\<empty>
# w:\workorder\region4\45678912\Final.doc
# 
# Results:
# ['34567891', '45678912']

job_folders = set([]) #set list is unique
out_list = [".pdf", ".ppt", ".txt"]

def get_filepaths(directory):
    """
    This function will generate the file names in a directory
    tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each
    directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself),
    it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).
    """

    folder_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.

    # Walk the tree.

    for item in os.listdir(directory):
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(directory, item)):
            folderpath = os.path.join(directory, item) # Join the two strings in order to form the full folderpath.
            if re.search('^[0-9]', item):
                job_folders.add(item[:8])
            folder_paths.append(folderpath)  # Add it to the list.
    return folder_paths
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you copy and paste the existing code from somewhere else? Because the docstring appears to be that of [`os.walk`](//docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)...

Your question is unclear on several points:

1. You state that the goal of the code is to "return a unique list (set) of all directories if they do not contain certain file types".

   - First of all `list` and `set` are different data structures.
   - Secondly, your code creates **one of each**: `job_folders` is a `set` of folder names containing numbers, while `folder_paths` is a `list` of complete paths to folders regardless of whether or not they contain numbers.
   - What do you **actually** want as output here?
2. Should "those directories that DO NOT contain files in the out_list" be defined recursively, or only include first-level contents of those directories? **My solution assumes the latter**

   - Your example is contradictory on this point: it shows `34567891` in the results, but **not** `region3` in the results. Whether or not the definition is recursive, `region3` *should* be included in the results because `region3` does not contain any files with the listed extensions under it.
3. Should `job_folders` be populated only with directories that satisfy the criterion about their contents, or with **all** folder names containing numbers? **My solution assumes the latter**

One [poor practice in your code](//stackoverflow.com/a/19158418/20789) that I'd highlight is your use of global variables, `out_list` and `job_folders`. **I've changed the former to a second parameter of `get_filepaths` and the latter to a second return value.**

Anyway, here goes the solution...

```
import os, re

ext_list = [".pdf", ".ppt", ".txt"]

def get_filepaths(directory, ext_list):
    folder_paths = []  # List which will store all of the full filepaths.
    job_folders = set([])

    # Walk the tree.

    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        _, lastlevel = os.path.split(dir)
        if re.search('^[0-9]', lastlevel):
            job_folders.add(lastlevel[:8])

        for item in files:
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(item)
            if ext in ext_list:
                break
        else:
            # Since none of the file extensions matched ext_list, add it to the list of folder_paths
            folder_paths.append(os.path.relpath(dir, directory))

    return folder_paths, job_folders
```

I created a directory structure identical to yours under `/tmp` and ran the following:

```
folder_paths, job_folders = get_filepaths( os.path.expandvars(r"%TEMP%\workorder"), ext_list )

print "folder_paths =", folder_paths
print "job_folders =", job_folders
```

Here's the output:

```
folder_paths = ['.', 'region1', 'region2', 'region2\\23456789', 'region3', 'region3\\34567891', 'region4', 'region4\\456789123']
job_folders = set(['12345678', '23456789', '34567891', '45678912'])
```

As you can see, `region1\12345678` and `region2\23456789\test` are **not** included in the output `folder_paths` because they **do** *directly* contain files of the specified extensions; all the other subdirectories **are** included in the output because they **do not** *directly* contain files of the specified extensions.

Comment: Okay...? What does that mean? Is his solution what you want or not? (And you should upvote answers that are useful to you, not just mine but all that are useful.)

Comment: Thanks for this! Using @Noctis Skytower example gets these results:
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859436\Test
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859436\Clerical
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859436\GFW
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859475
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859475\CLERICAL
\\server\WorkOrder\Region1\07859475\GFW

What I actually want is a unique list of folder names if no files in the ext_list is found in any sub-directory.  ex ['07859436', '07859475']

sorry for being unclear...I've been spinning on this for a while trying all sorts of different things.

Comment: ...i'm new here and terrible at formatting posts  :(

Comment: "What I actually want is a unique list of folder names if no files in the ext_list is found in any sub-directory" ==> Why should `CLERICAL` not **also** be in the output, given that `CLERICAL` **also** does not contain any files with the given `ext_list`? What is the rule by which `07859475` is to be included but `CLERICAL` is not to be included?

Comment: The `07859475` is my 8 digit key aka `JobID`.  It is my _primary key_ in a corresponding  database. I need to be sure users are storing a PDF somewhere in that _`JobID` Folder_...whether it's in a sub-directory called `CLERICAL` or `TEMP` doesn't matter. I just care that it exists.

My goal is to find the Jobs that don't have a PDF and are marked as 'Complete' in the database.

Comment: Then you should rewrite your code and the question to clarify that only the numeric segments of the folder paths are relevant. This was not at all clear from the original statement.

Answer (score 2):

Does this do what you want?

```
import os

def main():
    exts = {'.pdf', '.ppt', '.txt'}
    for directory in get_directories_without_exts('W:\\workorder', exts):
        print(directory)

def get_directories_without_exts(root, exts):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root):
        for file in files:
            if os.path.splitext(file)[1] in exts:
                break
        else:
            yield root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Edit:** After looking at your requirements, I decided to create a tree object to analyze your directory structure. Once created, it is simple to make a recursive query with caching that to find out if a directory "is okay." From there, creating a generator that only finds top-level directories that are "not okay" is fairly simple. There is probably a better way to do this, but the code should at least work.

```
import os

def main():
    exts = {'.pdf', '.ppt', '.txt'}
    for directory in Tree('W:\\workorder', exts).not_okay:
        print(directory)

class Tree:

    def __init__(self, root, exts):
        if not os.path.isdir(root):
            raise ValueError('root must be a directory')
        self.name = root
        self.exts = exts
        self.files = set()
        self.directories = []
        try:
            names = os.listdir(root)
        except OSError:
            pass
        else:
            for child in names:
                path = os.path.join(root, child)
                if os.path.isfile(path):
                    self.files.add(os.path.splitext(child)[1])
                elif os.path.isdir(path):
                    self.directories.append(self.__class__(path, exts))
        self._is_okay = None

    @property
    def is_okay(self):
        if self._is_okay is None:
            self._is_okay = any(c.is_okay for c in self.directories) or \
                            any(c in self.exts for c in self.files)
        return self._is_okay

    @property
    def not_okay(self):
        if self.is_okay:
            for child in self.directories:
                for not_okay in child.not_okay:
                    yield not_okay
        else:
            yield self.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Good succinct illustration of `os.walk`. As in [my solution](//stackoverflow.com/a/31347307/20789), the issue here is that @user3594678 is ambiguous about whether or not "containing" a file is recursive or not. Looks like you assumed non-recursive, as I did.

Comment: @user3594678 Does the new code work any better? It is a bit more complicated but should do what was asked (if I understood your problem correctly).

Comment: @DanLenski The second example has been designed to be recursive in all three methods of the `Tree` object. It is not entirely clear if this could be made simpler. You have to find the "roots" of dirty trees and return those if the problem is correctly understood.

Comment: this errors out for me. I'm on Python 2.7.8.   
`File "<module3>", line 55
    yield from c.not_okay
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax` 

I removed the `from` then get this:
`  File "<module3>", line 39, in __init__
    self.directories.append(type(self)(path, exts))
TypeError: must be classobj, not str`

Comment: @user3594678 Sorry about that! The code was written in Python 3.4.3 but has been corrected now. The code should work in Python 2.7.8 since the changes have been made.

Comment: thanks @NoctisSkytower ! still no dice: `File "<module3>", line 40, in __init__
TypeError: must be classobj, not str`

Comment: @user3594678 Oh, that would explain why I ignored the `type` function so much in the past. Please try again with the altered code. If that does not work, then `self.__class__(` could probably be replaced with `Tree(` instead.

Comment: This works! As @DanLenski pointed out, I need to rework my question. Each Region folder will have `Job` directories, which are always 8 digits. There could be none or many sub-directories within the `Job` directory. If a `exts` is found in any of these `Job` directories, that `Job` `is_okay`.  Any way to tweak it to do that?

Comment: \\server\e\Data\WorkOrder\Region1\08147236\DGN files
\\server\e\Data\WorkOrder\Region1\08147236\Documents
\\server\e\Data\WorkOrder\Region1\08147236\GFW      \\server\e\Data\WorkOrder\Region1\08147236\Images    
BUT found a __PDF__ in the ..\EXPORT dir so this Job Folder is "Okay"

Answer (score 0):

To get the file extension:

```
name,ext = os.path.splitext(os.path.join(directory,item))
if ext not in out_list:
    job_folders.add(item[:8])
```

Comment: "you'll have to remove the period in your extension list or alter the code slightly" ==> this is **incorrect**. [`os.path.splitext` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) clearly explain that the returned extension **includes** the period.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @DanLenski and @NoctisSkytower I was able to get this worked out. 
My `WorkOrder` directory is always the 7th folder down when walking `in_path` and I found that using `os.sep`.
I borrowed from both of your solutions and came up with the following:

```
import os, re

ext_list = [".pdf"]
in_path = r'\\server\E\Data\WorkOrder'

def get_filepaths(directory, ext_list):
    not_okay = set([])  # Set which will store Job folder where no ext_list files found
    okay = set([]) # Set which will store Job folder where ext_list files found
    job_folders = set([]) #valid Job ID folder

    # Walk the tree.
    for dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(directory):

        for item in files:
            root, ext = os.path.splitext(item)

            if len(dir.split(os.sep)) >= 8: #Tree must contain Job ID folder
                job_folder = dir.split(os.sep)[7]
                if ext in ext_list:
                    okay.add(job_folder)
                else: # Since none of the file extensions matched ext_list, add it to the list of folder_paths
                    not_okay.add(job_folder)

    bad_list = list(not_okay - okay)
    bad_list.sort()

    return bad_list

bad_list = get_filepaths( os.path.expandvars(in_path), ext_list )
```